# AttributeError in NetworkX, module has no max_clique attribute

Tags: python, networkx

like said in the title I have an attribute error.
Here is my code:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
with open ("testing.txt", "r") as myfile:
   Matrice=eval(myfile.readline())
   Matnum = np.array(np.array(Matrice))
   Matnum = Matnum.astype(np.int, copy=False)
   G.add_node(Matnum.shape[1])
   for i in range(0,Matnum.shape[1]):
      for j in range(i+1,Matnum.shape[1]):
         if Matnum[i,j] == 1:
            G.add_edge(i,j)
   print nx.max_clique(G)
```

for information the reading line is a Matrix created by another script:

```
Matrix([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ....... 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

[Download it for testing!](http://jud-alex.com/testing.txt)

Have you a solution?
Thks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The docs are a bit ambiguous about where this resides but the following worked for me:

```
In [4]:

G = nx.complete_graph(4)
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import clique
clique.max_clique(G)
Out[4]:
{0, 1, 2, 3}
```