# ImportError: cannot import name 'treewidth'

Tags: python, networkx

I have been trying to import the necessary modules from the NetworkX library but it keeps throwing the ImportError or the AttributeError.

I am using the NetworkX library for my final year project and I would like to use [this function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/approximation.html#module-networkx.algorithms.approximation.treewidth) to compute the treewidth decomposition for a given graph, values of which I need fore my other functions.

I have tried the following things:

1. Initially I tried importing the way suggested in the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/approximation.html#)

```py
import networkx as nx 
from networkx.algorithms import approximation

G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)

decom = approximation.treewidth_min_fill_in(G)
```

But this just gives me the following error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.approximation' has no attribute 'treewidth_min_fill_in'
```

2. I also tried importing it directly by using:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)

decom = nx.algorithms.approximation.treewidth.treewidth_min_fill_in(G)
```

But this just gives me the following error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.approximation' has no attribute 'treewidth'
```

3. Then I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483092/attributeerror-in-networkx-module-has-no-max-clique-attribute?answertab=votes#tab-top) and it works only in case of cliques but not when trying to import 'treewidth'.

```py
import networkx as nx 
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import treewidth

G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)

decom = treewidth.treewidth_min_fill_in(G)
```

But this just gives me the following error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'treewidth'
```

I haven't had any success finding a solution. Any help is appreciated!

NOTE: This is my first question on SO, hence please give any additional feedback on the format of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the networkx package do you use and how did you install it?

I have tried to do `pip install networkx` and then executed your code with Python 3.7:

```py
import networkx as nx 
from networkx.algorithms import approximation

G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)

decom = approximation.treewidth_min_fill_in(G)
print(decom)
```

and the output is:

```sh
(4, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x1070d4ef0>)
```

You can use try to see version of your module using:

```py
import networkx
print(networkx.__version__)
```

And what methods are used:

```py
import networkx
from networkx.algorithms import approximation

print(dir(approximation))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @andnik ! This is embarassing but upon further inspection I realised that the version of NetworkX on the university computers that I am using is 2.1, which indeed does not contain the required modules. I am a bit disappointed in me as a final year comp sci student by that oversight. I will give it a go on my personal machine when I get home as I can't install packages on uni machines. Nonetheless, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Happens to everybody, no problem. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install networkx` or `pip install --upgrade networkx` if networkx is already installed and then executed your code with Python 3.7:

`import networkx`

`from networkx.algorithms.approximation import treewidth`

`treewidth.treewidth_min_fill_in()`

this works fine on my system. Hope this will sort your issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Karlos ! Seems like the problem was with the version of NetworkX package installed on this machine. I will give it a go on my personal machine when I go home. Nonetheless, thank you for your answer!